# OGR/OSR Lon Lat convention

Tags: python, ogr, osgeo

When I project (lon,lat) coordinates I get a different result depending on the version of OGR/OSR.

```
osgeo.version_info
```

sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=9, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

```
import ogr, osr
lon,lat = 6.16800,44.88358
point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
point.AddPoint(lon, lat)
inSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
inSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
inSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
outSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
outSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(32631)
coordTransform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(inSpatialRef, outSpatialRef)
point.Transform(coordTransform)
point.GetX(),point.GetY()
```

(750192.6531073075, 4974901.243746961)

When I run the same code with another distribution of python, osgeo, I need to swap `lon` and `lat` in `AddPoint` to get the correct result.

```
point.AddPoint(lon, lat)

osgeo.version_info
```

sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=7, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

Is it documented somewhere? I would like to handle this in my code but I'm not sure from which version it has changed..

Answer (score 3):

Behavior was changed in version 3.0 (and was the reason to bump version into 3). Documentation is in https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc73_proj6_wkt2_srsbarn.

For getting the old behavior with GDAL 3 use

```
SetAxisMappingStrategy?(OAMS_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER)
```

Comment: Many thanks. I just added this line to keep the code compliant with older GDAL versions:
inSpatialRef.SetAxisMappingStrategy(osr.OAMS_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER)

Comment: try:  
        inSpatialRef.SetAxisMappingStrategy(osr.OAMS_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER)   
    except:  

        pass